# How to make an encoded POST request using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, httprequest, axios

I am trying to create a POST request in my reactjs app based on the following API request example:

**Example API request**

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4ZjAw...WY0MzE=" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

I'm supposed to be base64 encoding the text following "Basic" within the header.

How do I create this request in javascript using axios? This is what I have so far:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const encodedString = new Buffer('1ff56abe7792f426ea41a771d707d6690:1b2cca2dedd3949b0a6c5e1582446c9c5').toString('base64');

        const [initSpotResponse] = await Promise.all([
            axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', { headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}` } })
        ]);
    }
```

How do I include the "grant_type=client_credentials" part?

Comment: -d stands for `data`. So, add a new object `data: {grant_type: 'client_credentials'}` within the object of the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to axios’ [README](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#axiosposturl-data-config), this is the Request method aliases for POST requests

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

```
axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', 
    { data: { grant_type: ‘client_credentials’} }, 
    { headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}` } }
)
```

You could also do

```
const options = {
   url: ‘https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', 
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}` },
   data: { grant_type: ‘client_credentials’} 
};

axios(options);
```